# Where to find Maven repository for WSO2 Balana

Tags: java, maven, wso2, balana

Is there any public Maven repository of WSO2 Balana?

I'd like to use this dependency in my project pom

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wso2.balana</groupId>
  <artifactId>balana</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
<dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wso2.balana</groupId>
  <artifactId>balana-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
<dependency>
```

in order to run this code

```
Balana balana = Balana.getInstance();
PDP pdp = new PDP(balana.getPdpConfig());
pdp.evaluate(xacmlRequest);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are two actually, dependending on which version you depend on:

- One for versions before and including 1.0.0-wso2v7 [here](http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/org/wso2/balana/).
- One for versions after and including 1.0.0-wso2v8 [here](http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/balana/).

If you depend on Balana 1.0.1, you then need to add the second repository to [your POM or `settings.xml`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html):

```xml
<repository>
  <id>wso2-nexus</id>
  <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
```

And then declare the dependency with:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wso2.balana</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.wso2.balana</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
<dependency>
```

Comment: `compile group: 'org.wso2.balana', name: 'org.wso2.balana', version: '1.1.2'` this is what worked for my gradle project.

Comment: unfortunately for 2022 "Since Maven 3.8.1 http repositories are blocked."  and this dependency does not work. Several workarounds must be applied